# Wordress - How to write permalink rewrite rule from /?p=123 to /blog/%postname%/ in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to add  RewriteRule in a Wordpress .htaccess file

I would like to redirect any blog post that has permalink structure 
`/?p=123/` to `/blog/%postname%/`

For example :

I would like to setup automatic redirect from 
`https://freshmail.pl/?p=177125`

to 
`https://freshmail.pl/blog/czy-email-marketing-jest-skuteczny/`

In my Wordpress permalinks settings I got  Custom structure and :
`https://freshmail.pl/blog/%postname%/` but it somehow not redirecting /?p=123 to /blog/%postname%/ automatically

I've tried to add

`RewriteRule ^/.*$ /blog/$1/ [R=301,L,QSA]`

in my .htaccess but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=177125$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/czy-email-marketing-jest-skuteczny/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

You need to repeat the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` lines for every page.

Tested this on [htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be) and it works.

Comment: Is it possible to set up rule which redirect /?p=N , where N is a post ID number to 
/blog/%postname%/

Comment: As I understand it, p=177125 goes to `blog/czy-email-marketing-jest-skuteczny/ `and say `p=20000` goes to blog/just-another-page right? I don't believe there's an easy way to map `N` to `%postname%`. I'd just repeat the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` for each page redirect.